# Google OAuth2 - Fingerprint is already used

Tags: java, android, google-maps, oauth-2.0, google-api

I was using Google MAPS API and Oauth2. I wanted to move them to new gmail and firebase project. I deleted old account's firebase and google cloud api projects.

Firebase has been moved successfully with same SHA-1 KEY. But even though I changed package name fully, Google says "fingerprint is already used" and I can't move my sha1 for new gmail's oauth2.

How can I fix this? (I checked almost all posts about this but there is no obvious solution)

Comment: Google projects are temporarily stored for thirty days from the date of deletion for restoration purposes. I assume it is the reason for the conflict. (Not sure though)

Comment: Is there any way to get new one ?